# installed package "is not installable" on Xenial i386

Tags: ubuntu, apt, x86, 32bit

(Originally asked on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467968/installed-package-is-not-installable-on-xenial-i386) but it's off-topic there since
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life; and is also off-topic on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252952/installed-package-is-not-installable-on-xenial-i386). Third's the charm?)

Part of installing a package i'm maintaining is a `dist-upgrade`. I noticed that there have been recent changes in the repos, such as upgrading `libmysqlclient18` to `libmysqlclient20`, so i had to change my dependencies accordingly.

However, now i can't install my app because it depends on an installed package that is apparently not installable.

```
$ uname -a
Linux myvm 4.4.0-210-generic #242-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:57:00 UTC 2021 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ sudo apt install ./myapp-dep1.deb ./myapp-dep2.deb ./myapp-bin.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'myapp-dep1' instead of './myapp-dep1.deb'
Note, selecting 'myapp-dep2' instead of './myapp-dep2.deb'
Note, selecting 'myapp-bin' instead of './myapp-bin.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 myapp-bin : Depends: libhpdf (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ apt search libhpdf
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libhpdf-2.2.1/xenial,now 2.2.1-1.1 i386 [installed]
  C library for generating pdf files

libhpdf-dev/xenial,now 2.2.1-1.1 i386 [installed]
  C library for generating pdf files (development files)

$ find /usr/lib/ -name "libhpdf*"
/usr/lib/libhpdf.so
/usr/lib/libhpdf-2.2.1.so
```

The Depends line in my `DEBIAN/control` includes, among others, `Depends: .., libhpdf (>=2.2.1), ..` so what am i doing wrong?

At first i assumed they dropped i386 altogether, but it's still listed, at least in [some repos](http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libh/libharu/). The [Xenial page](https://ubuntu.com/16-04) states that Xenial's now in ESM, and the [ESM page](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) lists x86 as a supported architecture for Xenial. I do doubt my company has ESM support though, but can't get an official source on whether or not they dropped x86 for non-ESM.

I thought Xenial was the last version to support x86, following versions only supporting x86_64, but comments on the askubuntu thread say otherwise.

I tried to install using `aptitude` as suggested on the SO thread but cannot get it to install a local .deb file. Also tried with `dpkg` with similar results:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ./myapp-dep1.deb ./myapp-dep2.deb ./myapp-bin.deb
Selecting previously unselected package myapp-dep1.
(Reading database ... 112300 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./myapp-dep1.deb ...
Unpacking myapp-dep1 (2023.02.01.214-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package myapp-dep2.
Preparing to unpack ./myapp-dep2.deb ...
Unpacking myapp-dep2 (1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package myapp-bin.
Preparing to unpack ./myapp-bin.deb ...
Unpacking myapp-bin (1.0-420) ...
Setting up myapp-dep2 (1.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myapp-bin:
 myapp-bin depends on libhpdf (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libhpdf is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package myapp-bin (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up myapp-dep1 (2023.02.01.214-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 myapp-bin
```

...only it is still installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name is `libhpdf-2.2.1`, so your dependency needs to specify that:

```
Depends: ..., libhpdf-2.2.1, ...
```

Comment: Looking at history, 
`-- libhpdf-2.2.1, libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1)`

`++ libhpdf (>=2.2.1), libmysqlclient20 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1)`
makes sense.